# angular js to keep track of like and dislike click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to develope app in angularjs where i am reading json to read comments with like and dislike button . i am stuck at point where **i am not sure how to track if user has already clicked on Like for particular comment ??**

**data.json**::

```
[  {
    "name": "Anam",
    "age": 20,
    "id": 100,
    "commentline": "Yes Good !!!",
    "like":5,
    "dislike":1
  },
  {
    "name": "Moroni",
    "age": 50,
    "id": 101,
    "commentline": "Yes Good !!!",
    "like":5,
    "dislike":1
  },
  {
    "name": "Tiancum",
    "age": 43,
    "id": 102,
    "commentline": "Yes Good !!!",
    "like":5,
    "dislike":1
  },
  {
    "name": "Jacob",
    "age": 27,
    "id": 103,
    "commentline": "Yes Good !!!",
    "like":5,
    "dislike":1
  },
  {
    "name": "Nephi",
    "age": 29,
    "id": 104,
    "commentline": "Yes Good !!!",
    "like":5,
    "dislike":1
  },
  {
    "name": "Anam",
    "age": 20,
    "id": 100,
    "commentline": "Yes Good !!!",
    "like":5,
    "dislike":1
  }
]
```

**HTML ::**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="FundooDirectiveTutorial">
<head>
  <title>Rating Directive Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="rating.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <style>
  .sideheading
  {
    display: inline-block
  }
</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="FundooCtrl">


  <h2>Listing All Comments </h2>
  <br/><!-- 
  <div class="commentbox" ng-repeat="comment in comments" >
    <h4 class="sideheading">comment By:</h4>{{comment.name}}<br/>
    <h4 class="sideheading">Comment ::</h4>{{comment.commentline}} <br/>
    <h4 class="sideheading">Likes ::</h4> {{comment.like}} <br/>
    <h4 class="sideheading">Dislike::</h4>  {{comment.dislike}} <br/>

     </div>
 -->
     <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{comment.name}}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Comment ::{{comment.commentline}} <br/>
            Likes :: {{comment.like}}  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="incrlikes(comment)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Like
            </button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="decrlikes(comment)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> DisLike
            </button><br/>
            Dislike:: {{comment.dislike}} 
           <br/>
           likeflag::
            <br/>

          </div>
   </div>
  <!-- <div fundoo-rating rating-value="rating" max="10" on-rating-selected="saveRatingToServer(rating)"></div>
  <br/>
  Readonly rating <br/>
  <div fundoo-rating rating-value="rating" max="10" readonly="true"></div>
 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="comment.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS ::**

```
var app=angular.module('FundooDirectiveTutorial', []);



app.controller('FundooCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('comment.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.comments = data;
    $scope.incrlikes=function(a)
    {
            var selectedIndex=$scope.comments.indexOf( a );
            console.log('Likes increment'+a.name);
            console.log($scope.comments.indexOf( a ) +'with index of name is '+$scope.comments[selectedIndex].name   );
            $scope.comments[selectedIndex].like=$scope.comments[selectedIndex].like+1;
            $scope.likeflag=1;

     if($scope.likeflag==1)
     {       

          }else
          {
            console.log('Already like');
          }
    }
  });

});
```

Fiddle::

http://jsfiddle.net/simmi_simmi987/DeKP4/

Comment: @Stpal with every json object ?thats where i am stuck , for each comment how can i keep track

Comment: What do you want? Each comment/Every User?

Comment: every user..i want to track every user

Comment: Then you have to store, Users who liked/unliked the comment

Comment: @Satpal see suppose if i open browser and like comment by "Jacob" then its corresponding like should get increment by 1 and on again click on like it should show some msg like "already like and something"

Comment: @Satpal ng-show and hide can be used , but on click of button which variable i should set to false?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my this problem using ng-show and ng-hide,

when likeClicked is false then i show like button , and when user click it on it i change variable to false . so automaticaly , dislike button is shown

```
var app=angular.module('FundooDirectiveTutorial', []);



app.controller('FundooCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('comment.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.comments = data;
    $scope.likeClicked=[];
    $scope.incrlikes=function(a)
    {
            var selectedIndex=$scope.comments.indexOf( a );

            if(! $scope.likeClicked[selectedIndex])
            {
            console.log('Likes increment'+a.name);
            console.log($scope.comments.indexOf( a ) +'with index of name is '+$scope.comments[selectedIndex].name   );
            $scope.comments[selectedIndex].like=$scope.comments[selectedIndex].like+1;
            $scope.likeClicked[selectedIndex]=true;
          }
          else
          {
            console.log('Already like'); 
          }
    }

     $scope.decrlikes=function(a)
    {
            var selectedIndex=$scope.comments.indexOf( a );

            if($scope.likeClicked[selectedIndex])
            {
            console.log('Likes increment'+a.name);
            console.log($scope.comments.indexOf( a ) +'with index of name is '+$scope.comments[selectedIndex].name   );
            $scope.comments[selectedIndex].like=$scope.comments[selectedIndex].like-1;
            $scope.likeClicked[selectedIndex]=false;
          }
          else
          {
            console.log('Already Dislike'); 
          }
     }
  });

});
```